# get an access token with publish permission c#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

```
fb = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "app_id",
                client_secret = "app_secret",
                grant_type = "client_credentials",
                scope = "publish_stream,manage_pages"
            });
```

i am using this code to get an access token to publish to a page of mine. The access token that i get is shorter than the one that i get from the graph api explorer and when i debug it gives me the Application ID xxxxxxxxx and the name of the application with no other information(expires,issued,...)

can anybody help to get same access token as the graph api explorer and that can use to post

Answer (score 0):

`/oauth/access_token` is the endpoint for asking for an *app* access token. And asking for a `scope` for an app access token is nonsense, there is no “scope” for app access tokens.

If you want to get a *page* access token, you have to follow the flow as described here: [Login as a Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-page/)